# Upgrading osx driver for 10.11 (Changes in USB stack)

Tags: objective-c, kernel, usb, driver, osx-elcapitan

I am upgrading existing custom mouse driver devices to OSX 10.11. It is seen that apple has updated its usb stack.

Please refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_11/Objective-C/Kernel.html

My existing code uses many of the removed classes (`IOUSBHIDDriver`, `IOUSBInterface`, `IOUSBPipe` etc). Can someone help me in finding replacements or any useful information for upgrading to 10.11?

Many classes and header files are renamed, and I can figure out the replacements from the above link. But code also uses deprecated class `IOUSBPipe` and its methods. I have not fully understood what it is used for. Can someone explain purpose of `IOUSBPipe` as well as suggest me the alternative class for OSX 10.11?

Please find below this line a code snippet that deals with `IOUSBpipe`

```
IOMemoryDescriptor *report;
setReport(report, kIOHIDReportTypeOutput);
IOReturn ret;
IOUSBDevRequest request;

IOUSBFindEndpointRequest findRequest = {
    kUSBAnyType,
    kUSBAnyDirn,
    0,
    0
};

IOUSBPipe *pipe = NULL;

while(pipe=usbInterface->FindNextPipe(pipe, &findRequest))
{
if (!pipe)
{
    IOLog("NO PIPE!\n");
    return 0;
}
IOLog("control request on pipe!\n");

request.bmRequestType = (UInt8)req->bmRequestType;
request.bRequest = (UInt8)req->bRequest;
request.wIndex = (UInt16)req->wIndex;
request.wLength = req->wLength;
request.wValue = (UInt16)req->wValue;
request.pData = (void*)data;

pipe->ControlRequest(&request);
    IOLog("result: %d", data[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe basically represents one direction of a USB endpoint.  You can send or receive data from it.  I don't know much about kernel-level development in Mac OS X, but by looking at the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_11/Objective-C/Kernel.html) you posted, I suspect you are supposed to use **IOUSBHostPipe** now instead of IOUSBPipe.