# Symbols not found - IOUSBHostHIDDevice - OSX kext

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, usb, osx-elcapitan, kernel-extension

I had to convert an existing driver to OSx10.11 ([Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478569/upgrading-osx-driver-for-10-11-changes-in-usb-stack)).

I have replaced the deprecated and removed classes and methods to new ones introduced in 10.11. Now the kext builds successfully but cannot load the driver.

The `OSBundleLibraries` was updated after issuing command `kextlibs -xml driver.kext`.

```
<key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver</key>
        <string>4.4d69</string>
        <key>com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily</key>
        <string>2.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.bsd</key>
        <string>15.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>15.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>15.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>15.0</string>
    </dict>
```

Also , giving `-all` to `kextlibs` stated that 20 symbols were not found. Please find below the relevant portion result of the command.

```
22 symbols not found in any library kext:
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice5Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice17Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice0Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice14Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice9Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice11Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice4Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice18Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice8Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice15Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice3Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice12Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice7Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice19Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice2Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice16Ev
__ZN20IOBluetoothHIDDriver31_RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver12Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice13Ev
__ZN20IOBluetoothHIDDriver31_RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver11Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice6Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice1Ev
__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice29_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice10Ev
```

kextutil gave the following output

```
sudo kextutil -n -print-diagnostics prdt.kext
kxld[com.comp.driver.prdt]: The super class vtable 'vtable for IOBluetoothHIDDriver' for vtable 'vtable for com_MadCatz_driver_bt_RATTe' is out of date. Make sure your kext has been built against the correct headers.
kxld[com.comp.driver.prdt]: The super class vtable 'vtable for IOBluetoothHIDDriver' for vtable 'vtable for com_MadCatz_driver_bt_RATTe' is out of date. Make sure your kext has been built against the correct headers.
kxld[com.comp.driver.prdt]: The vtable for com_comp_driver_usb_prdt was not patched because its parent, the vtable for IOUSBHostHIDDevice, was not found.
Link failed (error code 5).
Check library declarations for your kext with kextlibs(8).
```

**What should be done to rectify the missing symbols?. How do I find where the symbols are located?.**

Any idea relating to the issue is highly appreciated, as I cannot figure out how to proceed.

Also, what does the `__ZN18`, `28_` etc represent in `__ZN18IOUSBHostHIDDevice28_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice5Ev`? Is there any way to trace the line of code in which the unknown symbols are located

******* edited to add additional info *******

## Additional Information

Demangled and sorted missing symbols from `kextlibs` result (listed above)

```
IOUSBHostHIDDevice::_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice0();
IOUSBHostHIDDevice::_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice1();
IOUSBHostHIDDevice::_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice2();
.
.
.
IOUSBHostHIDDevice::_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice17();
IOUSBHostHIDDevice::_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice18();
IOUSBHostHIDDevice::_RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice19();
IOBluetoothHIDDriver::_RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver11();
IOBluetoothHIDDriver::_RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver12();
```

It seems like the `RESERVEDIOUSBHostHIDDevice` (listed above) are declared in  `IOKit/usb/IOUSBHostHIDDevice.h`

```
//From IOUSBHostHIDDevice.h
// Protected pad slots for future expansion
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused(IOUSBHostHIDDevice, 0);
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused(IOUSBHostHIDDevice, 1);
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused(IOUSBHostHIDDevice, 2);
.
.
// Public pad slots for future expansion
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused(IOUSBHostHIDDevice, 10);
.
.
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused(IOUSBHostHIDDevice, 19);
```

However `RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver` is declared in `IOBluetoothHIDDriver.h`in which contains

```
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused( IOBluetoothHIDDriver, 0 );
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused( IOBluetoothHIDDriver, 1 );
.
.
.
OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused( IOBluetoothHIDDriver, 19 );
```

is declared, however, **Interestingly only `_RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver11()` and `_RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver12()` are the only methods that was not matched with kernel even though 1 to 19 were declared** in `IOBluetoothHIDDriver.h`.

where `OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused` is a macro declared in `OSMetaClass.h` as

```
#if APPLE_KEXT_VTABLE_PADDING
#define OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused(className, index)        \
    private:                                                      \
    virtual void _RESERVED ## className ## index ()
#else
#define OSMetaClassDeclareReservedUnused(className, index)
#endif
```

Comment: In `kextlibs` log, I found some lines that might give some clues. `__ZN11IOHIDDevice22_RESERVEDIOHIDDevice17Ev in /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext (2.0.0)`, `__ZN20IOBluetoothHIDDriver31_RESERVEDIOBluetoothHIDDriver13Ev in /System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothHIDDriver.kext (4.4.0d69)`

Comment: Regarding the `__ZN18`, `28_` etc.: this is C++ name mangling. If you pipe those symbols through the `c++filt` command it will convert them to C++ function signatures, which might help you debug the issue. I'll try to answer the other parts of the question over the next days when I'll hopefully have more time.

Comment: @pmdj Much thanks for pointing out `c++filt`. This is my first work with drivers, and clearly, I am a newbie. Any link to any resources (tutorials, forums for driver developers) from which I can learn will be a huge help.